# Django CreateView ModelForm dropdown field queryset filter

Tags: django

This is my first real go with Django (1.6) and I haven't been able to figure this out:

I'm trying to limit a dropdown on a CreateView to only show projects that have an active status (2) in the Project model:

```
class ProjectStatus(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=8)

class Project(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    status = models.ForeignKey(ProjectStatus)

class WorkLog(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User)
    log_date = models.DateField( default=datetime.date.today)
    accomplishments = models.TextField()
```

My forms.py:

```
class WorklogCreateForm(ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = WorkLog
    fields = [ 'project', 'log_date', 'accomplishments' ]

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(WorklogCreateForm, self).__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(Project.status == 2)
```

and my CreateView from views.py:

```
class WorklogCreate(CreateView):
    form_class = WorklogCreateForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('dashboard')
```

But I get the **error:**

```
TypeError at /log/add/
'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

If I change my filter to be `(Project.status.id == 2)` I instead get:

```
AttributeError at /log/add/
'ReverseSingleRelatedObjectDescriptor' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I think I'm close but don't quite have the firm grasp I need apparently. Any ideas?  Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to filter like this.

```
 self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(status_id=2)
```

Comment: Thanks!  That got me past that error, but now my form doesn't seem to be created.  First the view complained that no template_name was defined and after I specified it, then it stops at rendering, saying the form attributes don't exist.  I'm going to keep digging until I find out how deep this hole is :)

Comment: I moved the query into def get_form() of my CreateView (which I wanted initially) and now it seems to work.  Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You were close, but for some reason mixed in what looks like SQLAlchemy syntax.

Also, the idea of filtering your queryset by an arbitrarily assigned number (the PK) is absurd.

```
self.fields['project'].queryset = Project.objects.filter(status__name="foo")
```

would make a lot more sense, if only your status name were marked `unique=True`.